# Json result contains NaN for type miss match

Tags: json, google-fusion-tables

The v1.0 API is returning json values of NaN which is not valid JSON.

This is a reproducible error.

1. Create Fusion Table which a column that has a type of NUMERIC
2. Insert a record with the value of an empty string.
3. Query for that record.

Example table: 164EYrIvGHKG1IRSXbG6_MD1kqHcvs0Vm-nRlRE4

```
INSERT INTO 164EYrIvGHKG1IRSXbG6_MD1kqHcvs0Vm-nRlRE4 (Text,Number) VALUES ('Null','')
SELECT * from 164EYrIvGHKG1IRSXbG6_MD1kqHcvs0Vm-nRlRE4 where Text = 'Null'
```

If you try this query in the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/fusiontables/v1/fusiontables.query.sql?sql=SELECT%20%2a%20from%20164EYrIvGHKG1IRSXbG6_MD1kqHcvs0Vm-nRlRE4%20where%20Text%20%253D%20%27Null%27&_h=12&) it will fail as it can not parse the resulting JSON.

The Expected result would be for either the insert to fail or for the result to be converted to null

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reporting this.  I've created an internal issue to track this.